# Get ids of checked boxes which are not disabled

Tags: jquery

I want to get the ids of all the check boxes which are checked and enabled, ie those checkboxes which are disabled and checked, should not be counted.

Here is my code:-

```
var widgets_list = [];
$("#dialog-form input:checkbox:checked").map(function(){
    widgets_list.push($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

The current code adds checkboxes which are disabled and checked, which I dont want. How do I add a functionality which will take into account only enabled checkboxes.

Comment: `var widgets_list = $.map($("#dialog-form input:checkbox:checked:not(:disabled), function(el) {return el.id})`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
var widgets_list = $("#dialog-form input:checkbox:checked").map(function(){
    if(!this.disabled)
       return this.id;
}).get();
```

or

```
var widgets_list = $("input:checkbox:checked:not(:disabled)").map(function(){
       return this.id;
}).get();
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tRCtV/)**

*map is used to convert one collection to another collection in this case checkboxes to array of ids, so you can avoid a push which you would generally do with a loop (.each)*

Comment: +1 I like the elegance in your code.  Love to follow your coding style :)

Answer (score 2):

Try like this

```
$("#dialog-form input:checkbox:checked").not(":disabled").map(function(){
    widgets_list.push($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2u4VE/)

What you need to know is [**`.not()`**](http://api.jquery.com/not/) and [**`:disabled`**](http://api.jquery.com/disabled-selector/) pseudo selector.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [:enabled](http://api.jquery.com/enabled-selector/),

```
$("#dialog-form input:checkbox:checked:enabled").map(function(){
    widgets_list.push($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/tRCtV/5/)

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty simple.Just add `enabled`.Something like this.

```
var widgets_list = [];
$("#dialog-form input:checkbox:checked:enabled").map(function(){
widgets_list.push($(this).attr('id'));
});
```